# How to scrape all the titles and links from Google search results (Python + Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape the titles and links from Google search results using selenium (Python). My problem is that I'm only able to scrape the first 4 results, but not the other 6. Here, the results are just empty. My feeling is that this might has something to do with the loading time of the web page, but I'm not sure. I have been looking at implementing the `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located` statement, but haven't found a way of making it work.

Anyone with experience on this issue? Much appreciated!

Code:

```
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

root = "https://www.google.com/"
url  = "https://google.com/search?q="

query = 'Why do I only see the first 4 results?' # Fill in google query
query = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)
link = url + query

print(f'Main link to search for: {link}')

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(link)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
headings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "g"]') #Heading elements
   
for heading in headings:
    
    title = heading.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')
    links = heading.get_attribute('href') # This ain't working either, any help?
    print(links)
    #link = heading.find_element_by_name('a href')
    for t in title:
         print('title:', t.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to only obtain div elements with the class "g". However, by looking at a sample search result myself i have noticed, that not *every* search result is an element of the class g. Some differ.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAbsA.png

You need some different kind of selector, e.g. by iterating through the exact div that contains every "search-result-element" and filter valid ones by checking each elements attributes that match a normal search result.

EDIT:

your try to get the link via the attribute "href" probably doesnt work as well because in my case, search results with the class "g" dont have any *direct* href attributes. Theres alway an a-tag followed by a href attribute, like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldDEs.png

considering that the first a-tag in a search result is always the one you're looking for, you could search through the sub-elements of your heading for the FIRST a-tag that's found and then get the "href" attribute from it, something like that:

```
href = heading.find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("href")
```

Comment: Thanks! I do find that underneath all sections do have a class "g". Therefore, I can now load all the href's. However, not all titles. Any clues on this?

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly specified locators for links.
**Solution**

```
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

root = "https://www.google.com/"
url = "https://google.com/search?q="

query = 'Why do I only see the first 4 results?'  # Fill in google query
query = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)
link = url + query

print(f'Main link to search for: {link}')

options = Options()
# options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get(link)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class = "g"]')))
headings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "g"]')  # Heading elements

for heading in headings:

    title = heading.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')
    links = heading.find_element_by_css_selector('.yuRUbf>a').get_attribute("href")  # This ain't working either, any help?
    print(links)
    # link = heading.find_element_by_name('a href')
    for t in title:
        print('title:', t.text)
```

Please note that the only 2 things I fixed were:

1 The way you get the locator

2 Explicit waits. You did not use them as you should have to.

**Output:**

```
 Main link to search for: https://google.com/search?q=Why+do+I+only+see+the+first+4+results%3F
   https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14972/why-on-the-first-page-google-says-there-are-thousands-of-results-but-on-the-last
    title: Why on the first page Google says there are thousands of ...
    https://www.ltnow.com/how-to-get-more-than-10-results-per-page-in-google-search/
    title: 
    https://www.theleverageway.com/blog/how-far-down-the-search-engine-results-page-will-most-people-go/
    title: 
    https://www.impactplus.com/blog/google-is-limiting-number-of-search-results-per-domain-to-have-more-diversity-in-listings
    title: 
    https://www.forbes.com/sites/forbesagencycouncil/2017/10/30/the-value-of-search-results-rankings/
    title: 
    https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-intersect/wp/2015/06/30/always-click-the-first-google-result-you-might-want-to-stop-doing-that/
    title: Always click the first Google result? You might want to stop ...
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Four
    title: First Four - Wikipedia
    https://neilpatel.com/blog/first-page-google/
    title: How to Show Up on the First Page of Google (Even if You're a ...
    https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-first-page-clicks/374516/
    title: Over 25% of People Click the First Google Search Result
    https://www.theleverageway.com/blog/how-far-down-the-search-engine-results-page-will-most-people-go/
    title: How Far Down the Search Results Page Will Most People Go?
    https://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2020/08/19/get-on-first-page-google
    title: 10+ Free Ways to Get on the First Page of Google | WordStream
    https://books.google.ca/books?id=teyaAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=Why+do+I+only+see+the+first+4+results?&source=bl&ots=iBI-YaNJNc&sig=ACfU3U0GpAnPsH_zTbblyRv1C6eS5xwCUg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-psHB_NjwAhURHs0KHWi-AC0Q6AEwD3oECBEQAw
    title: PISA Knowledge and Skills for Life First Results from PISA ...
    https://books.google.ca/books?id=8dY8AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=Why+do+I+only+see+the+first+4+results?&source=bl&ots=x-7WRKNzXs&sig=ACfU3U13RRTc66oxnpWC6WW-CMwyyIAm8A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-psHB_NjwAhURHs0KHWi-AC0Q6AEwEHoECA8QAw
    title: OECD Skills Outlook 2013 First Results from the Survey of ...
    https://books.google.ca/books?id=zWwVAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=Why+do+I+only+see+the+first+4+results?&source=bl&ots=u7XMk6B6Qz&sig=ACfU3U2Q8kNocn8W3HHkFxxJnV0b58WYoA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-psHB_NjwAhURHs0KHWi-AC0Q6AEwEXoECBAQAw
    title: Results of the First Joint US-USSR Central Pacific ...
```

Titles for **People also ask** are not returned because they have a different locator.

Comment: Great elaborate answer, thanks! I'm trying now to get all the titles of the page, but so far it's not coming through. The `title = heading.find_element_by_css_selector('.yuRUbf>a>h3').text` ain't working. Any clues on this?

Comment: Can you add html code of at least one search result?

Comment: Sorry vitaliis I don't know how/what to send exactly. I'm getting some of the titles now with the line `title = heading.find_element_by_css_selector('.yuRUbf').text
` , but not all.